# Prove that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^n} {1+e^t}dt=(1-2^{-n})n!\zeta (n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

I have encountered the following identity on Wolfram alpha and I fail proving it (with $n \in \mathbb N^*$) $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^n} {1+e^t}dt=(1-2^{-n})n! \zeta(n+1)$$

I tried to rewrite the term inside the integral as a power series,  without success.

I know an identity that may be useful though 
$$(1-\frac{1}{2^n})\zeta(n+1)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {(-1)^{k-1}}{k^{n+1}}$$
(see one of my previous post).

Comment: Similarly, $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{t^n}{e^t-1}dt=\Gamma(n+1)\zeta(n+1)$ , where $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [Geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

$$\frac{1}{1+e^t}=\frac{e^{-t}}{1+e^{-t}}=e^{-t}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{m}e^{-mt}$$

so $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{m}e^{-mt}t^ndt$$

$$I=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{m}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-t(m+1)}t^ndt$$

$$t(m+1)= u$$

$$I=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{m}}{(m+1)^{n+1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}u^ndu$$

$$I=(1-2^{-n})\zeta{(n+1)}\Gamma{(n+1)}$$

Comment: You should add a justification when you swap the integral and the sum, this is not trivial.

Comment: @GabrielR. I edited it :)